# External F5 load balancer integration with Docker swarm service discovery

Tags: docker, load-balancing, service-discovery, f5, docker-swarm-mode

I'm planning to use docker swarm mode for my applications to host. Currently in a situation to figure out a way of integrating F5 load balancer with docker swarm mode service discovery. Is there a use case to achieve this? I know we can publish the ports with host and route traffic to host ip from F5 but that will limit me to run just task per host.

Could I use Consul as service discovery and have the hostnames for the services so I will have a bind dns setup to forward dns requests to consul?

Suggestions/Idea's are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your intended application, if I was using Service Discovery VIPs rather than DNSRR, I would treat each advertised VIP as the node behind the BIG-IP VIP.  That way, you can use BIG-IP's iControlREST to add/modify/delete nodes as they're spun up in Swarm's Service Discovery.

Curl example: `curl -sk -u 'admin:admin' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://x.x.x.x/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool -d '{"name":"test-pool","members":[{"name":"Server-Bob:443","address":"10.0.0.1"}]}'`

Using the above idea, you would have a published application via the BIG-IP, and you would add/remove docker service discovered VIP's on the fly via Ansible/Python/Whatever.

You could use Consul for service discovery but I think you'd be creating redundant functions since Swarm can complete the similar discovery tasks.  Adding Bind DNS requirements wouldn't make management that much easier.  Technically there's a lot of ways you could do this but that way makes the most sense to me if you already have established BIG-IP infrastructure.  If I am missing something in your application requirements let me know and I can modify my answer.